# Blog mini graph for views is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, superuser-blog

When logged in to the Super User blog and viewing a post, I can see the following up at the top:

[image]

Before it used to show a little mini graph, but when we moved over to BlogOverflow (Super User was separate before), it shows this. When attempting to click it, I get:

[image]

Having said this, once I go over to the Gaming blog, I can see both pages, and the mini graph is up.

[image]

Can we get our permissions straightened out?

Comment: That, and writers not being able to preview posts. Statistics allow us to know what to focus on...

Comment: Yep. Statistics were never installed after being moved to blog overflow. I've asked the devs multiple times to take care of it and so far they haven't. I'll bug them about it again.

Comment: @TomWijsman I can view all the previews, odd

Comment: @SimonSheehan: But I guess you are an editor, not a writer.

Comment: @TomWijsman Ah that I am, good point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed.

When the blog was moved over from it's previous separate install to be part of the Blog Overflow network install of community blogs, the settings for the site stats were not transferred over.